# Page unresponsive when starting a VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[image]

Many a time while starting a vm instance on GCP, I face this error- "Page unresponsive" an the screen freezes for a few minutes. Is this a bug in chrome or GCP?

Comment: Did you try to use web ssh when this happen or it just happened while browsing Google Cloud console? Chrome displays this message when there are long running scripts which can affect user experience.

Comment: Perhaps create a new Chrome User definition which will then run Chrome without any of your current plugins.  This will then eliminate many potentials.   You asked if it was a bug in Chrome or GCP.  The answer may be neither ... but is instead a bug in one of the 3rd party plugins you may have installed in chrome.